# How do I increase the RAM using an external device to my computer

Tags: memory, ramdisk

If my laptop has an available RAM of 8GB how can I can make the available RAM to be increased to say 8+128 GB. I am not sure if this could be done, but I guess there are devices like RAID servers etc which when attached to the computer will provide the computer with more RAM.

So are there such devices available? What else is required to enable them to increase a computer's RAM ie. can I attach it by USB and what softwares are required (among other things)?

Comment: _"devices like RAID servers etc which when attached to the computer [...]"_ - your understanding of what RAID and server are seems to be off. You may want to read up on these concepts or refrain from using these terms.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. RAM mainly has:

- Low latency (tens of nanoseconds)
- High bandwidth (easily 20+ GiB/s)

You cannot achieve this without direct connection to the CPU. Not even PCI Express cards (in the same system) could do it.

If you want more RAM, there are no shortcuts: You need more *RAM*. If your notebook isn’t terribly old, it probably can be upgraded to at least 16 GiB.

Comment: Some modern laptops have soldered RAM and no slots. In that case upgrade is not possible, or at least not feasible for average user.